# How to change text style of the Title & Description text controls of a WiX dialog?

Tags: wix

Where can I find information of the Style values for a text control of a WiX dialog?

For example, the default text style used for the WiX dialog Title control is **{\WixUI_Font_Title}** & I would want to use the same style but to change the color to **White**.
For the Description control I would like to use the default style but with the color **Yellow**?

Comment: You can get some inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954688/how-can-i-change-the-font-colour-and-type-of-a-string-in-wix-in-one-of-the-stand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The source code of WiX has the UIExtension at this folder: src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib, in it you can find the WixUI_Minimal.wxs file.

Then you will find this line:

```
<TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
```

In case you want to change the color to white, do the following:

```
<TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9"
           Bold="yes" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />
```

Finally, copy the file to our project and add a reference to it. To avoid any issues, rename the UI.Id to something like `WixUI_Minimal_Custom`.

Comment: So far as I can tell, this does not work. Even changing the UI element Ids results in a massive number of "duplicate symbol" errors. This is with trying to modify WixUI_Minimal

Comment: doesn't contain full instructions i.e. how to use the two TextStyles you've detailed