# Unable to change style of Wix Welcome Dialog test using TextStyle

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I am using Wix 3.10. I would like to change the style of the text on the Welcome Dialog of one of the built in Wix dialog sets, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972685/339939).

I have in my UI section:

```
<UI>
        <TextStyle Id="White12" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255"  />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
        ...
</UI>
```

And in my Localization .wxl:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
    <String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription"> {\White12}Our Welcome Text</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

When I build this, I get the following warning:

```
LGHT1076: ICE31: Text Style tag in WelcomeDlg.Description has no effect. Do you really want it to appear as text?
```

Indeed, the text isn't styled and the style code appears verbatim in the dialog.

Am I doing this wrong? All the relevant posts I can find about this say this should work.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but have you checked if the whitespace character after `>` and before `{` matters in the `<String>` element?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, that was it! Can't believe it was that simple... I didn't even realise the typo. Thanks.